# Is it possible to get the number of all existing ROS_Nodes or to shut down all Nodes except one?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to shut down all Nodes except 1 within a C++ program. Therefore I want to count the number of ROS_Nodes and kill n-2 nodes. ( My_Node and roscore shall still exist).
Or is there any other way to do so?

Thanks for your Help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288742/is-it-possible-to-get-the-number-of-all-existing-ros_nodes-or-to-shut-down-all-nodes-except-one?/) by [bambucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34656/bambucha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
To avoid an xy-problem, it might be good if you could clarify *why* you want to do this. It might not be necessary.

**Comment by [bambucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34656/bambucha/) on 2018-04-16**:
I need it, because I have to restart Gazebo with another enviroment. But the Linux-Computer is remote controlled to this. Therefore I have to shut down every ROS_Node, except the one which handles the remote.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
If you can manage the state of "your node", then would deployment using Docker perhaps be an option? Reusing `roscore` instances is not necessarily always very stable (left over parameters, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use a combination of the [Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) and [Slave API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Slave_API) to do what you want (first retrieve all registered nodes, iterate over them, compare their names and request the ones you don't want/need any longer to shutdown).

See #q271776 (among others) for a question that deals with something similar.

> Therefore I want to count the number of ROS_Nodes and kill n-2 nodes. ( My_Node and roscore shall still exist).

Note: I would recommend to do this by name, not "by number". That seems very brittle.

Also: `roscore` is not a node.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bambucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34656/bambucha/) on 2018-04-16**:
sorry for the mistake with the roscore and node! And thanks for the post [#q271776](https://answers.ros.org/question/271776/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-process-ids-of-ros-nodes/), I saw this before. My Problem is to understand this. Because I have never used Python before. Thanks :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
Well, it's mostly XML-RPC, so you could do the same thing using C++. It's just that the libraries that are already there are in Python.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
Could I ask you to mark the question as answered if/when you feel it has been answered? Thanks.